# Show that this is an entire function

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

If $f$ is an entire function, I have to show that $g(z):= \overline{f(\overline {z})}$ is also an entire function. How can I proof this if $g:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: As shown here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/551458/complex-conjugates-of-holomorphic-functions